# Using result from inner grain in Orleans

Tags: c#, orleans

I am trying to understand how Grains work in Orleans. My program will stall when I try to use the result from an inner grain in an outer Grain.

Will the inner grain be blocked by the context of my outer grain, so I can never get the result from an inner grain?

```
public class OuterGrain : Grain, IOuterGrain
{
    public Task<string> GetFormattedTime()
    {
        var innerGrain = GrainFactory.GetGrain<IInnerGrain>(1);
        var innerGrainTask = innerGrain.GetCurrentTime();
        return Task.FromResult(innerGrainTask.Result.ToString("yy-MM-dd"));
    }
}

public class InnerGrain : Grain, IInnerGrain
{
    public Task<DateTime> GetCurrentTime()
    {
        return Task.FromResult(DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the corrent async/await pattern, never use the blocking `.Result` or `.Wait()` methods in an async method (that returns `Task` or `Task<>`)

```
public class OuterGrain : Grain, IOuterGrain
{
    public async Task<string> GetFormattedTime()
    {
        var innerGrain = GrainFactory.GetGrain<IInnerGrain>(1);
        var innerGrainResult = await innerGrain.GetCurrentTime();
        return innerGrainResult.ToString("yy-MM-dd");
    }
}

public class InnerGrain : Grain, IInnerGrain
{
    public Task<DateTime> GetCurrentTime()
    {
        return Task.FromResult(DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```